# Table generated by PHP isn't displaying?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a build a html table from `php` code by accessing a `mysql` database but using the  tag is showing an empty page.

I cut down the code as below:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo "<b>Value1</b>";
echo "<table border="1"><tr><td>row 1, cell 1</td></tr></table>";
?>
</html>
</body>
```

I'm still getting the blank page, can someone please point out the error?

Comment: It may or may not be the source of your problem, but your closing `</body>` and `</html>` tags are the wrong way round

Comment: `/body` should come before `/html`

Comment: Try `<table border='1'>` or `<table border=\"1\">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace this line:

```
"<table border="1"><tr><td>row 1, cell 1</td></tr></table>"
```

With this line:

```
"<table border='1'><tr><td>row 1, cell 1</td></tr></table>"
```

You needed to escape the quotes around the border value.

Also, be sure to swap `</html>` and `</body>` round as you're closing them in the wrong order, like so:

```
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line has quotes in that need to be escaped:

```
echo "<table border="1"><tr><td>row 1, cell 1</td></tr></table>";
```

Change it to:

```
echo "<table border=\"1\"><tr><td>row 1, cell 1</td></tr></table>";
```

Basically, what's happening is when your code sees that `"1"`, it thinks you're leaving the string to enter some PHP code. Because you then don't put a valid thing next (such as `.` or `;`) it's throwing a syntax error.

To make it realise that you mean those as actual speech-marks, you need to put a slash before them.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="1"
```

The double quotes opened and closed in php means that the echo function is closed and opened again. so, using a single quote will work..

```
<table border='1'>
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

error is in line

```
echo "<table border="1"><tr><td>row 1, cell 1</td></tr></table>";
```

since you are enclosing string in double quotes your syntax is getting broken at "1..

use

```
echo "<table border=1><tr><td>row 1, cell 1</td></tr></table>";
```

or

```
echo '<table border="1"><tr><td>row 1, cell 1</td></tr></table>';
```

I will prefer second one .. because when you enclose string in double quotes it looks for php variable and hence increases the parsing time .... which in your case is absolutely not necessary